# Javascript Reactjs: is there a way to run MySQL queries as a form

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, reactjs

I'm creating a database project using Javascript: React, Node and MySQL.
I am not sure if there is a way to run MySQL queries as a form? Like, if I type in the form `"DELETE FROM table WHERE x = 1"` it will run the query after clicking a button.
I tried to establish connect and query using this link: [Node.js MySQL](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mysql.asp) but when I put all the file as a function, it threw me the error "net.connect is not a function". 
Any help is appreciated!

EDIT: here's the create connection file

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var fs = require('fs');

//Establish connection, replace password with your MySQL database's password
var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "xxx",
    database: "pdm"
});

// Export database as table.json file
con.connect();
con.query('SELECT * FROM pdm.newonlineretail', function (err, results, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
    // write the result as json
    fs.writeFile('table.json', JSON.stringify(results), function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('Query succeeded');
    });
    con.end();
});
```

when I make all the file as `export default function runSelect(){...}` to put it in another file to run, it throws the above error.

Comment: You might try `con = mysql.createConnection({debug: true});`. This will print debug info to stdout. https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#debugging-and-reporting-problems

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, Have you ever tried use Sequelize or Knex.js ? It allows you to import a database syntax into your application.

You forgot to define the dialect. You should add a filed as a dialect: "mysql" when you create a connection.

One more tip: you must install the "mysql2" as a dependencie otherwise you'll be using an outdated library